# How to replace all sets of duplicated lines with these same sets of lines but modified - all at once?

Tags: search, text, replace, duplicates, notepad++

While working on a data-kind list of text in Notepad++, i've wanted to change the attributed values into the "none" word in each line by selecting them into a column selection, which worked great.

But here come the problem... Now I finshed doing what I wanted to do in the list, I currently want to put real id values with digits that could replace all the "none" word but in a specific way. 
That list i'm working in is actually near 5k lines along with about 2k lines that include multiples set of duplicated lines.

For this reason, I must admit that i'm gonna have a very hard time if i'm deciding to do it manually because of the painfulness long work of the thing... Maybe a little tricky to explain so here examples:

```
<obj name="wall.ZOL" id="none"
<obj name="wall.ZOL" id="none"
<obj name="wall.ZOL" id="none"
<obj name="wall.XYZ" id="none"
<obj name="wall.XYZ" id="none"
<obj name="wall.XYZ" id="none"          <------------- In my actual document
<obj name="wall.DOR" id="none"
<obj name="wall.DOR" id="none"
<obj name="wall.DOR" id="none"
<obj name="wall.BUL" id="none"
<obj name="wall.BUL" id="none"
<obj name="wall.BUL" id="none"
```

In the example above, as you see, there is 12 lines but it include only 4 different type of data as only the name change so lets say that these 4 type of data are just 4 sets of duplicated lines. Here the second example:

```
<obj name="wall.ZOL" id="4130"
<obj name="wall.ZOL" id="4130"
<obj name="wall.ZOL" id="4130"
<obj name="wall.XYZ" id="5340"
<obj name="wall.XYZ" id="5340"
<obj name="wall.XYZ" id="5340"          <------------- How I would like it to be
<obj name="wall.DOR" id="1700"
<obj name="wall.DOR" id="1700"
<obj name="wall.DOR" id="1700"
<obj name="wall.BUL" id="9500"
<obj name="wall.BUL" id="9500"
<obj name="wall.BUL" id="9500"
```

And in this second above, there is exactly the same text but only the id that has changed. As you can see, the numbers are in replacement of the "none" word instead, while respecting that the id changes only if the name="[name]" from the line is changing.

So here what I would really be able to do, for example when pressing CTRL+H;

```
            WHILE SEARCHING FOR...        

        <obj name="wall.ZOL" id="none"
        <obj name="wall.XYZ" id="none"
        <obj name="wall.DOR" id="none"
        <obj name="wall.BUL" id="none"

       ...AND THEN "REPLACE BY" THIS...

        <obj name="wall.ZOL" id="4130"
        <obj name="wall.XYZ" id="5340"
        <obj name="wall.DOR" id="1700"
        <obj name="wall.BUL" id="9500"

 ...TO GET THE RESULT IN MY DOCUMENT LIKE THAT:

        <obj name="wall.ZOL" id="4130"
        <obj name="wall.ZOL" id="4130"
        <obj name="wall.ZOL" id="4130"
        <obj name="wall.XYZ" id="5340"
        <obj name="wall.XYZ" id="5340"
        <obj name="wall.XYZ" id="5340"
        <obj name="wall.DOR" id="1700"
        <obj name="wall.DOR" id="1700"
        <obj name="wall.DOR" id="1700"
        <obj name="wall.BUL" id="9500"
        <obj name="wall.BUL" id="9500"
        <obj name="wall.BUL" id="9500"
```

So this is like I would like to do. Even though I found similar case like this problem, I didnt found any threads that could help me to do the exact same thing with the exact same kind of text, knowing there is more than a thousand of lines to process in mine.

I also tried searching in that nicely made Notepad++ software but unfortunately, I didnt find any option allowing it even though i'm pretty sure its possible to do that with regex command or (maybe?) a plugin extension. If someone knowing better than me could help, this would be great (please).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You'd better write a script in your favorite scripting language.**

---

But, if you really want to use Notepad++ and If the number of ids is not too high (because it will become unreadable), you can do the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<obj name="wall\.(?:(ZOL)|(XYZ)|(DOR)|(BUL))" id="\Knone`
- Replace with: `(?{1}4130:(?{2}5340:(?{3}1700:(?{4}9500))))`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<obj name="wall\.   # literally
(?:                 # non capture group
    (ZOL)               # group 1
  |                   # OR
    (XYZ)               # group 2
  |                   # OR
    (DOR)               # group 3
  |                   # OR
    (BUL)               # group 4
# you can add more groups if you need them.
)                   # end group
" id="              # literally
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
none                # literally
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?{1}               # if group 1 exists (i.e. "ZOL")
  4130                # id value for "ZOL"
 :                  # else
  (?{2}               # if group 2 exists
    5340                # value for "XYZ"
   :                  # else
    (?{3}               # if group 3  exists
      1700                # value for "DOR"
     :                  # else
      (?{4}9500)          # if group 4 exists, value for "BUL"
    )                   # endif
  )                   # endif
)                   # endif
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Oh, its indeed possible like that and it works! I never saw something like this before so its really good to know. Yeah I would preferably use only npp for all my needs. The command you gave me is the most important part as this is what it serve my need, but as you said, its better I found a way to make this command work on the 2k different name in my list to accelerate the process. Thank you!

Comment: @SabhClarence: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Ah, sure! I've just waited until I find the right tactic with the regex command you gave me to implement all the ≈2k names and I found one way. However, for the users in the same case as me its preferable to use Multiline find and replace from ToolBucket plugin for very long text as what I have is too long for the regular CTRL+H find/replace. Anyway, without your help I couldn't have done it so thank you again.